# Please help me understand this formula for Fourier analysis

Tags: infinity

[image]

I'm a programmer with a poor knowledge of math. Could anyone tell me how to read the infinity above the sigma, and the n=1 below the sigma?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation |
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics))

Comment: why do you need to understand this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a summation notation,it means the addition of all the terms starting from n = 1 to n= infinity

Comment: so $a_1$sin(2pift)...+$a_2$sin...